# How to generate text log file of Revisions from Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I need to generate a text log file of all the revisions made in certain period. We're using Collabnet Subversion on Server and on client AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN.

I have got to know that it can be generated by svn log command, and I tried but none of them were working on Client machine as well as Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the revisions that were created over a period of time, you have to use [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.log) together with a shell command. If you look at the options of `svn log`, you see there no range definition by date, you can only specify the range of revision numbers.

If you look at TortoiseSVN, there is the option to define the range by date. Do the following steps:

- Select in the Windows Explorer the directory for which you are interested in the revisions made. If you have no checkout location, open the repository browser instead.
- Open from the context menu `TortoiseSVN > Show log` or in the repository explorer `Show log`.
- At the top, you have the option to select the range of dates.
  [image]

So you could then define the range of revisions, and have then to clarify which information of the log you are interested in.